# Using DataStore on Android With Java

Tags: java, android, datastore

I have been trying to to migrate from `SharedPreferences` to `DataStore`. So far I have had no success. The way I had my `SharedPreferences` implemented before is like this. I have a `SharedPreferencesManager` that I store my `SharedPreferences` instance in. The `SharedPreferencesManager` also handles all my editing and so on for my `SharedPreferences`. When the Apps `Activity` goes through `OnCreate` the `SharedPreferencesManager` constructor calls this method:

```
private void createSharedPreferences(Context context)
{
    mSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int unlock = mSharedPref.getInt(SHARED_PREFERENCES_CREATED, - 1);
    if (unlock == - 1)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(SHARED_PREFERENCES_CREATED, 0);
       //The rest of the default values are excluded for brevity
    }
}
```

As you can probably see I create the `SharedPreferences` instance and query if its been created. If not add the default values.

I would like to keep this structure with DataStore but it seem impossible.

I have followed the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore). Inserted the dependencies created my `DataStore` instance like such: `mDataStore = new RxPreferenceDataStoreBuilder(context, PREFERENCE_NAME).build();`and got a basic POC using the code supplied. I tried to apply it to the structure I have like this it:

```
private void createDefaultPreferencesValues()
{
    if(!areDefaultsInserted())
    {
        setDefaultValuesAdded(true);
        //Default values excluded for brevity
    }
}
```

with the `areDefaultsInserted()` method structure like this:

```
 public boolean areDefaultsInserted()
{
    return mDataStore.data().map(prefs -> prefs.get(DEFAULT_INSERTED_KEY)).blockingFirst();
}
```

Initially I got `java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper function returned a null value.`. This makes sense since I didnt insert anything into the `DataStore`. So I tried catching the exception
and then `finally` passing out a false, but still got the `The mapper function returned a null value`. I tried multiple other ways but the one that caused me the most confusion was this.

```
private void createDefaultPreferencesValues()
{
   if(mDataStore.data().blockingFirst().asMap().isEmpty())
   {
        setDefaultValuesAdded(true);
       //Values excluded for brevity
    }
}
```

I can successfully check that the `Map` is empty but when I then try to assign a value into the `DataStore` I get the `The mapper function returned a null value` exception again. Stranger still if I remove the check for the `Maps` size I can successfully add the default values. Im obviously doing something wrong. How do I catch the `null` and insert a set of default values. Is it even worth it to use `DataStore` since it seems like a lot of overhead to store and fetch one literal bit of information? I am not querying `Urls` on the net or anything. A user can flip a switch and change the value. When they return the value gets fetched and applied to the Ui. Please help. Brain is too smooth :(

Ps. Answers in Java please. The project is Java based